# Python Dataframe to convert column name as row value

Tags: python

I am very new to python. Could you please provide me solution?

I have the input like this:

```
    Calendar    X    Y
0   2020-01-01  10  22
1   2020-02-01  15  45
2   2020-03-01  13  67
3   2020-04-01  33  89
```

Expected output is :

```
Type    Calendar     Act_Value    
X       2020-01-01    10
X       2020-02-01    15
X       2020-03-01    13
X       2020-04-01    33
Y       2020-01-01    22 
Y       2020-02-01    45
Y       2020-03-01    67
Y       2020-04-01    89
```

Comment: StackOverflow is no service for solutions. It is a plattform to get help. So please provide your thoughts so far.

Comment: look into `pd.melt()`

Comment: Apologies @Jacob. Actually I was looking for help. I tried pivot, but didn't help. Next time, I will provide my thoughts with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @GodWin mentioned, `pd.melt()` is a way to do this. This is from the `pandas` module which is the most popular data tool in Python. You can get more information from https://pandas.pydata.org/, and here is a quick suggestion on how you can achieve your output.

```py
## import module
import pandas as pd

## create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({
"Calendar":["2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01","2020-04-01"],
"X":[10,15,13,33],
"Y":[22,45,67,89]})

## output
print(pd.melt(df, id_vars="Calendar", var_name="Type",value_name="Act_value"))

#################################
     Calendar Type  Act_value
0  2020-01-01    X         10
1  2020-02-01    X         15
2  2020-03-01    X         13
3  2020-04-01    X         33
4  2020-01-01    Y         22
5  2020-02-01    Y         45
6  2020-03-01    Y         67
7  2020-04-01    Y         89
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the relevant libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Replicate the dataframe you have stated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"Calendar": "2020-01-01", "X": 10, "Y": 22}, {"Calendar": 
"2020-02-01", "X": 15, "Y": 45}, {"Calendar": "2020-03-01", "X": 13, "Y": 67}, 
{"Calendar": "2020-04-01", "X":33, "Y": 89}])
```

Apply [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) in order to receive your required result:

```
df_unpivoted = df.melt(id_vars=['Calendar'], var_name='Type', 
value_name='Act_value')
df_unpivoted.set_index('Type')
```